# How can show AJAX response as HTML page?

Tags: ajax, debugging, firebug-lite

I am trying to upload some files to the server, but I get an error from the server. The server sends an HTML page to explain the error, the browser receives ajax   response that has an error but it does not render it as HTML page, So, how can I render ajax response to show as HTML? Is there any way to show AJAX responses as HTML page?

[image: Response in Firebug Lite]

Comment: There is no JSON/AJAX response - just a server 500 error (with HTML). If it is a GET you can get a fair replication by simpling copy+paste'ing the URL into a new browser window; this won't work for POST, etc. In any case, consider using a tool like [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) (a Chrome extension) to 'play with restful-like web API calls'.

Comment: Side note: You are using Firebug Lite, which is unmaintained for several years now and its usage is discouraged. Instead you should use the developer tools integrated into the browsers or Firebug (the Firefox extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chrome can render the AJAX response page as HTML page, So you can get that from developer tools -> the Network button -> XHR Name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the *Response* tab **is** the response. That means, you got an HTTP 500 status code (Internal Server Error) and that is the response for it.

An internal server error means that there is some misconfiguration on the server-side, i.e. you need to search the problem in your server configuration or the server-side script that gets called. Therefore, the client-side tools can't help you much with this problem.

Comment: yeah, you are right, but I need to read the error first to fix on the server side, I know I can copy the AJAX response (HTML) and save it on the file then open the file in a browser, but I need a fast way to show the AJAX response on a browser

Comment: All built-in browser developer tools and Firebug (the Firefox extension) should show you the rendered response additionally to the source.